# PHP 5.6 encoding latin1 MySQL encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, latin1

After migration from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.6 I have encoding problem. My MySQL database is latin1 and my PHP files are in windows-1251. Now everything is displayed like "ñëåäíèòå àäðåñè" or "�����".

It should be display something in Cyrillic like "кирилица". I've tried mysqli_set_charset but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Firstly, does switching back to PHP 5.3 resolve the issue? Secondly, is the textual data in your PHP files? Your database has never been able to hold Cyrillic text, so the problem cannot be your database. If you wish to hold Cyrillic text, a latin1 charset cannot do so (and I doubt a file encoding of windows-1251 can do so either). I would switch the database to UTF-8 (but be careful that data that has been incorrectly converted is not corrupted even further). Your PHP files should be saved as UTF-8 also, in your editor - again watch out that your data is not further corrupted.

Comment: If there is only a small amount of text and you can manually fix it, the easiest approach is to swap both your database and file encodings to UTF-8 (in the database it is a collation called something like `utf8_general_ci`) and then fix data that is corrupted by hand.

Comment: Yes, switching back to PHP 5.3 resolve the problem. My database is in latin1 and it hold Cyrillic text, which is display correct in PHP 5.3. I saved my PHP files as UTF-8 but nothing change.

Comment: Mysql on different machines?

Comment: There is something very strange going on there. Latin1 simply cannot hold Cyrillic characters. I think you must be holding it the wrong character set and then converting it in PHP to render in Cyrillic (and we'll need to see a database text sample and some PHP code to be able to advise further - please edit your question). This is an issue that needs fixing anyway - stick with PHP 5.3 and swap your database to UTF-8, and get it working like that first. Obviously, back everything up so that incorrect charset conversions do not corrupt your data.

Comment: Done incorrectly, latin1 can hold Cyrillic characters.  And the fact that it can leads to problems festering and possibly bad characters coming back.  Cyrillic (at least in utf8) needs 2 bytes per character.  With transcoding during the `INSERT`, you get '?' (not �), and you have lost the data.  Without transcoding -- that is, throwing 2 Cyrillic bytes at a latin1 column, without translating, and the bytes are blindly stored.  (latin1 does no checking.)

Answer (score 1):

First, let's see what you have in the table.  Do `SELECT col, HEX(col)...` to see how these are encoded.  Here is the HEX that should be there if it is correctly utf8-encoded:

`ñëå` --> `C3B1C3ABC3A5`; `кир` --> `D0BAD0B8D180`

If you don't get those, then the problem was on inserting, and we may (or may not) be able to repair the data.  If you have `C390C2BAC390C2B8C391E282AC` for the Cyrillic, then you have "double encoding", and it will take some work to 'fix'.

utf8 needs to be established in about 4 places.

- The column(s) in the database -- Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to verify that they are explicitly set to utf8, or defaulted from the table definition. (It is not enough to change the database default.)
- The connection between the client and the server. See `SET NAMES utf8`.
- The bytes you have. (This is probably the case.)
- If you are displaying the text in a web page, check the `<meta>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Halfer is right. Change both your PHP and MySQL encoding, first the PHP with

```
mb_internal_encoding ("UTF-8"); 
mb_http_output("UTF-8");
```

to UTF-8, at the top of your PHP pages.

*If you miss out the `"UTF-8"` and print the output from these finctions, it will show you your current PHP encoding - probably windows-1251*

Also note that with MySQL you need to change the character encoding on the row in the table as well as on the table itself overall and on the database itself overall, as the defaults will remain `latin1` so any new fields you add would be latin1 without being carefully checked.

If you are trying to save Cryllic text to the database you will need the correct Cryllic character set in the database, rather than latin1